# Navigation of folder structure on remote webserver and treeview

Tags: c++, qt

I would like some advice on how to create a treeview, and a model, for remote folder navigation. I already have a method (let's call this **Navigate**) that takes a path as parameter and returns the list of subdirectories. I started from the example in [here](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/itemviews-simpletreemodel.html), which got me on the right direction.

I have a few problems though: first of all, I would like lazy loading, i.e. I only call the Navigate function on the root path I want to navigate, then when the user selects a folder, I call the Navigate function again on that path. The only problem with this approach is that I have to click twice on a folder to make it expand, I guess because the first time there is not yet any child in that node (I still haven't updated the child list through Navigate); this is not a big problem, at least for the moment.

The problem is that this approach seems to work only for the first two levels: I get the list of the root node, I can get the list of any child of elements from this list, but then this second list is not shown, even though the data function is called on the nodes itself! At this point I get an exception in `QHashData::allocateNode`, but I don't have any clue regarding this since I cannot debug the Qt libraries.

Do you have any idea on this? Alternative approaches?
thanks!

Comment: Need some more paragraphs in there ;)

Comment: @NicholasSmith You can always edit yourself, even with 524 reputation.

Comment: @teukkam: I might not be able to split in the most relevant manner

Comment: It seems that using the 4.7.4 version everything works fine, but the problem with the "double click" remains...